# Executed 0 of 1 (skipped 1) ERROR in Jasmine

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

My testing dependencies are as follows

```
"jasmine-core": "2.99.1",
"karma": "3.1.3",
"karma-chrome-launcher": "2.2.0",
"karma-jasmine": "1.1.2",
"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "0.2.2"
```

And I am getting `Executed 0 of 1 (skipped 1) ERROR` and a pending spec in the browser window.

The code snippet below is my test specification:

```
describe('Aymans first test', () => {
    let sut; // System under test
    beforeEach(() =>{
        sut = {}
    })
    it('should be true'), () => {
        sut.a = true;

        expect(sut.a).toBe(true);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a misplaced closing round bracket in `it`.

```
it('should be true'), () => {
    ...
}
```

should be changed to...

```
it('should be true', () => {
    ...
});
```

Comment: Such a silly typo. Thanks for the resolution. Appreciate it! :)

Comment: Glad I could help. Please consider accepting the answer if you think it was the solution to your question (see stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)